# RDS Performance slow compared to local mysql install

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a RDS server (rd3.medium) on AWS that is running basic configuration. I'm trying to run this query, which runs in a few milliseconds on my local computer, as well as a basic web server where I have MySQL server installed. However, when I run it on RDS it takes **20 seconds.** I'm using General Provisioned SSD's for storage.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        p2.id
    FROM
        wp_posts p2
    INNER JOIN
        wp_postmeta pm2
        ON
            pm2.meta_key = 'wpcr3_review_post'
            AND
            pm2.post_id = p2.id

    INNER JOIN
        wp_posts p3
        ON
            p3.id = pm2.meta_value
            AND
            p3.post_status = 'publish'
    INNER JOIN
        wp_postmeta pm3
        ON
            pm3.meta_key = 'wpcr3_enable'
            AND
            pm3.meta_value = '1'

    WHERE
        p2.post_type = 'wpcr3_review'
```

I did notice when I ran `EXPLAIN` that it uses a temporary table, and so I wonder if there's some way in which RDS doesn't handle that well, while a basic MySQL server install does?

```
1   SIMPLE  pm3 ref meta_key    meta_key    576 const   334 Using where; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE  pm2 ref post_id,meta_key    meta_key    576 const   1335    Using where
1   SIMPLE  p2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,type_status_date    PRIMARY 8   deaddictioncentres_staging.pm2.post_id  1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  p3  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   deaddictioncentres_staging.pm2.meta_value   1   **Using index condition;** Using where; Distinct
```

The only difference that I find on all other servers is the RDS server adds the **Using index condition;** where none of the others do.

**Update**
I found out the difference of **Using index condition;** was due to moving from 5.5 to 5.6. But I can't understand why moving from 5.5 to 5.6 would make things so much slower.

Comment: What does the query plan look like on your local machine?

Comment: Do the versions of MySQL differ between your local machine and you RDS instance? Does the amount of data differ?

Comment: Version is 5.6 on RDS and 5.5 on my server, but I struggle to see how upgrading to 5.6 could make things so much slower on  a relatively standard query.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the answer. The problem was due to the bad query design. (This query was coming from a Wordpress Plugin, so it's not surprising). The third join was not only worthless, it was attaching "creating" 1 record in the result set for every record in the Post Meta table that had wpcr3_enable set to 1 * every record in the WP Post table, resulting in 500,000 rows. I believe the speed on local was just an issue with the sending/processing of that data. The added DISTINCT keyword was just covering up the issue, and is actually unnecessary in a properly coded query.